# Writing custom basic_streambuf

Tags: c++, streambuf

After some time implementing my own streambuf I askes myself if you can use different types for the basic_streambuf like double. Are there any experiences and use cases here?

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you try to solve with your `streambuf` class? *Why* do you need it to store its data in `double`? Please read about [the XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) and think about how it relates to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're missing the point of `streambuf`. It's the **back end** of `std::stream`. The **front end** is provided by `operator<<` and `operator>>`. Those are overloaded for `double`. The frond end converts any type to characters, the back end does the I/O (to file, screen, network, whatever)

Comment: What about not using characters in the backend but double. What if there is no need to store characters.

Comment: @Gustavo: how would you write a `std::string` to such a backend? Remember, `std::streambuf` is part of the whole `<iostream>` library. If your use case differs too much from the typical uses of `<iostream>`, you'll find limited benefit in adapting `<iostream>`.

Comment: So it is right that only characters are allowed in the iostream environment and it was never intended using other types than char?

Comment: @Gustavo: Well, there's `wchar_t`. But yes, it's all about characters.

Comment: @Gustavo any `T` for which `std::char_traits<T>` has sensible members